# How to download and save a file using drakma:http-request and flexistreams

Tags: common-lisp, binary-data

I am trying to download and save a PDF but it fails while writing with an EOF-Error.
What would be the correct way of doing this?

```
(with-open-file (file "/home/*/test.pdf"
                      :direction :io
                      :if-does-not-exist :create
                      :if-exists :supersede
                      :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (let ((input (drakma:http-request "http://www.fractalconcept.com/ex.pdf"
                                    :want-stream t)))
    (awhile (read-byte input)
      (write-byte it file))
    (close input)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was that I forgot to use the two optional parameters of `read-byte`.

The correct way would be to set `eof-error-p` and `eof-value` to `nil`:

```
(with-open-file (file "/home/*/test.pdf"
                      :direction :output
                      :if-does-not-exist :create
                      :if-exists :supersede
                      :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (let ((input (drakma:http-request "http://www.fractalconcept.com/ex.pdf"
                                    :want-stream t)))
    (awhile (read-byte input nil nil)
      (write-byte it file))
    (close input)))
```

Comment: Since you are only outputting, you should use `:direction :output`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(ql:quickload "trivial-download")
(trivial-download:download URL FILE)
```

; Does pretty much exactly what your code does but in bigger chunks and can show a progress bar.

; QuickLisp can be found at http://QuickLisp.org.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the answer does not work for HTTPS URLs. Streams being read to EOF cause an unexpected closed SSL stream for `cl+ssl`. There's some more involved stuff happening, see https://github.com/edicl/drakma/issues/138 for more info. However, a temporary workaround, I have stolen from https://github.com/cl-plus-ssl/cl-plus-ssl/issues/166#issuecomment-1742175637 should solve the `cl+ssl` related errors when downloading files over HTTPS with `:want-stream t`.

```
(defun download-file (from-url to-file)
  (with-open-file (stream to-file :direction :output
                                  :if-exists :overwrite
                                  :if-does-not-exist :create
                                  :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
    (multiple-value-bind (input status-code response-headers)
        (drakma:http-request from-url :want-stream t :force-binary t)
      (unless (= 200 status-code)
        (error "Something wrong with the status code: ~s" status-code))
      (dotimes (x (parse-integer (cdr (assoc :content-length response-headers))))
        (write-byte (read-byte input nil nil) stream))
      (close input))))
```